# Object reference null for the same statement in asp.net

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, object-reference

I am facing a strange problem while running my application.

I have a class [Say studentInfo], for which I am declaring a instance above the page load [i.e. of page scope]

```
StudentInfo sInfo;
```

on Page_load I am calling this instance to call functions of that class and everything is working fine:

ex: `string studentName = sInfo.GetStudentId(studentId);`

But when I am writing the same above code in the different function on the same page, I am getting this error:

Object reference can not be set to null

```
private infoList GetInfo()
{
 int studentId = // some logic;
 string studentName = sInfo.GetStudentId(studentId);
}
```

Comment: you are probably calling this method before `Page_Load`.

Comment: Could you paste a little bit more code, like e.g. where you set `sInfo`?

Comment: It depends on where SInfo gets intialized and where GetInfo gets called. But it seems you use GetInfo() before the sInfo gets intialised.

Comment: @Adeel I am calling the method GetInfo() on postback.

Comment: @Pieter I am calling the same method string studentName = sInfo.GetStudentId(studentId); from page_load and it is working fine but giving runtime error when it is placed in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring the variable, but not creating it

try `StudentInfo sInfo = new StudentInfo ();`

Comment: I thought that I have declared the instance for the scope of the page so it should work fine, but it is not. When I am creating a new instance also I am getting the same runtime error.

Comment: @zerotoinfinite Where are you creating the instance? you need to create it every time the page is used. by default it will not retain its state for postback and needs to be created/fetched again.

Comment: It is resolved now. I created a new instance again and it worked.